# replace a lists in a list of lists in mathematica

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

I have a list of lists, similar to what is below, I need to replace each {"S","D","U"} list in the overall list with a number.. Thanks in advance!

```
A = {{"S", "D", "U"}, {"S", "D", "U"}, {"S", "D", "U"}, {"S", "D", 
  "U"}, {"S", "D", "U"}, {"S", "D", "U"}, 1, {"S", "D", "U"}, {"S", 
  "D", "U"}, {"S", "D", "U"}, {"S", "D", "U"}, {"S", "D", "U"}, {"S", 
  "D", "U"}, {"S", "D", "U"}, {"S", "D", "U"}, {"S", "D", "U"}, {"S", 
  "D", "U"}, 1, {"S", "D", "U"}}
```

Comment: What have you got so far ?  Or are you just looking for someone to do your work for you ?

Comment: Thanks High Performance, That was very helpful.

Comment: Which number?  Are you familiar with ReplaceAll and Rule?

Comment: @user2372443, add examples of INPUT and DESIRED OUTPUT.

Answer (score 1):

```
A /. {"S" -> 1, "D" -> 2, "U" -> 3}
```